# como seleccionar un numero determinado de checkboxs segun un input TYPE 'number'

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un `input` type= 'number' que selecciona minimo 1 al 8 (máximo 8 checkboxs)

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="8" id="boleto_2d" size="5" name="boletos[2D][cantidad]" placeholder="0>
```

y tengo un grupo de checkbos traídos desde la base de datos en total son como 30

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectasiento[]"  id="<?php echo $Cod_SalAsi;  ?>" value="<?php echo $Cod_SalAsi;  ?>">
```

como hago para poder seleccionar según el input? he estado intentando y nada...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando cambia cada checkbox, puedes chequear si ya se ha cumplido el limite, de otra manera desactivar el checkbox activado (`checkItems()`).

Cuando el valor cambia en el input, puedes desactivar los checkbox recorriendolos (`limitCheck()`).

```js
function checkItems(sel){
  // obtener los checkboxes
  var checks=document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
  var checked=0;
  for(var i=0; i<checks.length; i++){
    // mantener chequeado si el valor del item es menor que el seleccionado
     if (checked>=sel.value){
        checks[i].checked=false;
        continue;
    }
    if (checks[i].checked){
      checked++;
    }
  }
 

}

function limitCheck(chk){
  // obtener los checkboxes
  var checks=document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
  var checked=0;
  for(var i=0; i<checks.length; i++){
    // mantener chequeado si el valor del item es menor que el seleccionado
    if (checks[i].checked){
      checked++;
    }
  }
  var boletos=document.getElementById("boleto_2d").value;

  if (checked>boletos){
     chk.checked=false;
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="8" id="boleto_2d" size="5" name="boletos[2D][cantidad]" value="1" onchange="checkItems(this)">

<input type="checkbox" name="selectasiento[]" onclick="limitCheck(this)" value="1" >1
<input type="checkbox" name="selectasiento[]" onclick="limitCheck(this)"  value="2" >2
<input type="checkbox" name="selectasiento[]" onclick="limitCheck(this)"  value="3" >3
<input type="checkbox" name="selectasiento[]" onclick="limitCheck(this)"  value="4" >4
<input type="checkbox" name="selectasiento[]" onclick="limitCheck(this)"  value="5" >5
<input type="checkbox" name="selectasiento[]" onclick="limitCheck(this)"  value="6" >6
<input type="checkbox" name="selectasiento[]" onclick="limitCheck(this)"  value="7" >7
<input type="checkbox" name="selectasiento[]" onclick="limitCheck(this)"  value="8" >8
```

Comment: mmm pero deja darle click a todos si es posible aunque en el input solo este un 2

Comment: Creo que ahora entendi mejor lo que quieres lograr, revisa el ejemplo. Un detalle no esta claro, que es cuando el valor se diminuye y ya estan checkeados el limite de items. Cual se desactiva? (en el ejemplo se desactiva el ultimo chequeado que sobre)

Comment: muchas gracias sos el mejor!!!